# How to delete one bar on a graph in Excel under the condition that it is equal to another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work with products that I have to track the growth of. We visualize multiple products growth with identification of the product on the y, growth % on the x, and then multiple bars for each product representing years. The last bar on the chart is an "All Products" growth capturer which just averages the growth of all the products included in the chart.

The issue: there are moments where there is only data for 1 product, but the "All Products" bar still appears. In this instance, the "All Products" bar is telling me the same thing as the Product's bar is because it is the only one available. "All Products" is just the average of 1 item in instances like that. Is there anyway I can write a formula so that if it is ever the case that there is only 1 product, and that the information for the 1 product matches the "All Products," to delete the All Products bars from the chart and leave just the Product by itself?

Comment: You can do that on the data, not in the chart itself. Add a "if" to the cell you calculate the average and to its title ("All Products"). If you need more explanation, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)